# Mysql, select from table multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database.

Couples table:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|  ID | Partner 1 | Partner 2           |
+---------------------------------------+
|  1   | 101       | 102                |
+---------------------------------------+
```

B table:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | name                 | date      | Letter | Phonenumber
+--------------------------------------------------------------
| 101| Mark                 | 1/1/2001  | D      | 061234
| 102| lisa                 | 1/1/2002  | E      | 061235
```

I cant quite figure out how to do the following:

Select from couples table the partners 1 & 2.
From partner 1, grab the name, date, letter & phonenumber.
From partner 2, grab the name, letter and date.
Do this for every couple in the couples table

I cant figure out how to do this, anyone know how? I have been stuck for quite some time now haha.
something like this

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | name | date      | Letter | Phonenumber | name | Letter| date
+------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | Mark | 1/1/2001  | D      | 061234      | lisa | E     | 1/1/2002 
+------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join twice - once for each partner. e.g.:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name, p1.date, p1.letter, p1.phonenumber, p2.name, p2.letter, p2.date from couples
 JOIN B on (B.id = partner_1) as p1
 JOIN B on (B.id = partner_2) as p2
```

My syntax may not be perfect, but it sounds like you know enough SQL to not need a copy+paste solution, just a pointer on how to solve.

Comment: Exactly, I do not really like copy pasta cuz i dont really learn from it.

Comment: Small push like this helps me continu, thanks!

Comment: `JOIN B on (B.id = partner_1) as p1` is incorrect.. it should be `JOIN B as p1 on (p1.id = partner_1)`.. same goes for `JOIN B on (B.id = partner_2) as p2` ..